# How can we find memory leak in Server side php.inc memory limit?

Tags: php, debugging, xampp

I been using XAMPP form past two weeks, and all of a sudden it showed up an error like `"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 3741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_database\1.php on line 820"`

then after some googling i came to know about a quick picture that you can change the memory limit in php.inc file... i changed it from 128 to 256.. but still it showed the same error.. then i changed it to 1024MB.. then again it showed error like

```
"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_database\1.php on line 820"
```

then i actually "read" the answer carefully and realized that this is some kind of memory leak causing by a bug.

now the question is how can i find and eliminate this bug?

ERROR show on following code::

```
<?php include('1.php'); ?>
<?php
$servername  = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "*****";
$dbname = "the_database";
$addtext = $_POST['addtext'];
$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
VALUES ('$addtext', '$date')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Your Answer has been Succesfully posted")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="answer.php"></a>';
}
else {
echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Any Help Would be Appreciated..

Comment: Show the code which causes this, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: This code is a mess and syntax highlight shows this.

Comment: What should i change in it..?

Comment: Which is line 820, where the error is?